# View criteria missing in jdeveloper 12.1.3

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

We are having a cascading LOV ->  Deaprtment, class(inputComboBoxWithLOV). Class LOV is filtered with selected value of Department. When I follow the below steps:

1. select a department
2. click on the down arrow to show filtered results, I see filtered classes with the selected department. Select a class and tab out.
3. clear the class field, again click on the down arrow to show filtered results.(P.S : Department field is not touched) But the class field is not showing filtered results. But when I clicked on More... to display the Search and select popup, I could see the filtered results.
   Only the the combobox dropdown values were unfiltered.

On Debugging, found that the viewCriteria which was applied to filter using Department is missing. The entire Where clause is missing.

This is occurring after our latest migration to 12.1.3, earlier we were using jdeveloper 11g and never faced this issue.

Any pointers about this issue will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LOV UI hints "Filter Combo Box Using" option was unchecked, when I checked it and tried I was able to see filtered results in the dropdown.

However I did not understand why it was not picking values from existing view criteria from the view object definition related to the LOV's view accessor and why should I explicitly check this option.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a 12.1.3 ADF BUG. You should fill in a Service Request with Oracle about it.
If you don't have a SR account, I will be happy to fill one in your behalf, if you can provide a sample workspace running on HR schema where we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have posted this because I was not sure if this was already raised. I tried looking up but did not find any, and hence was waiting to be sure before I filed a SR